# Why is my recursive FParsec parser throwing exception when it parses a nested array?

Tags: parsing, f#, fparsec

I'm trying to use FParsec to parse a TOML array.  I've worked through several parsers for various parts of the 0.5 spec, including arrays.  However, when I try to support nested arrays, I ran into a little trouble.  Here's what I've got:

```
let pArrayOf<'a> (parser:Parser<'a,_>) : Parser<'a list, unit> =
    pchar '[' >>. (sepBy parser (spaces >>. pchar ',' .>> spaces)) .>> pchar ']'
let pBasicStringArray = pArrayOf pBasicString
let pLiteralStringArray = pArrayOf pLiteralString
let pMultilineLiteralStringArray = pArrayOf pMultilineLiteralString
let pMultilineStringArray = pArrayOf pMultilineString
let pIntegerArray = pArrayOf pInteger
let pFloatArray = pArrayOf pFloat
let pBoolArray = pArrayOf pBool
let pOffsetDateTimeArray = pArrayOf pOffsetDateTime
let pLocalDateTimeArray = pArrayOf pLocalDateTime
let pLocalDateArray = pArrayOf pDate
let pLocalTimeArray = pArrayOf pTime

let pStringArray = (attempt pBasicStringArray) <|> (attempt pLiteralStringArray) <|> (attempt pMultilineLiteralStringArray) <|> (attempt pMultilineStringArray)

let mapObj (l:'a list) = List.map box l
let pArray,pArrayRef = createParserForwardedToRef()
pArrayRef :=
    choice [
        attempt pStringArray |>> mapObj;
        attempt pIntegerArray |>> mapObj;
        attempt pFloatArray |>> mapObj;
        attempt pBoolArray |>> mapObj;
        attempt pOffsetDateTimeArray |>> mapObj;
        attempt pLocalDateTimeArray |>> mapObj;
        attempt pLocalDateArray |>> mapObj;
        attempt pLocalTimeArray |>> mapObj;
        attempt pArray
    ]
```

Obviously there is more code here that isn't shown; in particular, the value parsers (`pBasicString`, `pInteger`, etc) aren't shown.  I'm assuming they work correctly, but anyone can look at them here: https://github.com/aggieben/FPConfig/blob/d4dc081dcefcee57fc1b45da69ac2178a1e10b2a/src/FPConfig.Toml/Parsers.fsx

The problem comes in when I tried to use the `createParserForwardedToRef` technique.  When I test this parser, I get an error:

```
> test pArray "[1,2,3]";; 
Ok: [1; 2; 3] <null> (Ln: 1, Col: 8) val it : unit = ()

> test pArray "[ [1,2], [3,4] ]";;


error FS0193: internal error: Object reference not set to an instance
of an object

>
```

As you can see, `pArray` works fine for a regular array, but a nested array blows it up.

What might be causing this?

Comment: Don't have time for a full answer right now, but when `pArrayRef` gets all the way down to `attempt pArray`, it hasn't consumed any `[` characters yet. After defining `pArray` with `createParserForwardedToRef`, you need to actually use it in a `pArrayOf` parser, e.g. `let pNestedArray = pArrayOf pArray`, then have `attempt pNestedArray` in your `pArrayRef`.

Comment: Also, I would prefer something with `>>?` rather than `attempt` for reasons of error handling, but I *really* don't have time to type up the reasons for that one.

Comment: Yeah, I'm going to have to come back on error messaging.  I'm not sure how `>>?` would fit in to how I have these things designed right now, but for sure the error messaging coming from these `attempt` parsers is pretty horrific

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will still not be a complete answer, but to expand on my earlier comment: consider how `pArrayRef` parses the string prefix `[ [`. It walks all the way down `pStringArray`, `pIntegerArray`, `pFloatArray`, etc., all of which will fail on the second `[` and backtrack to the first `[`. Then at the end you hit the recursive call `attempt pArray`. At this point the parser hasn't yet consumed anything (all those `attempt`s backtracked out to before the first `[`), so you make a recursive call to `pArrayRef` (via `pArray`) and start the loop again. And again, and again... What you've written here is an infinitely-recursive loop. The fact that this fails with a null reference error instead of a stack overflow error is probably due to some detail of FParsec's internal implementation.

What I think you need to do is the following:

```
let pArray,pArrayRef = createParserForwardedToRef()
let pNestedArray = pArrayOf pArray
pArrayRef :=
    choice [
        attempt pStringArray |>> mapObj;
        attempt pIntegerArray |>> mapObj;
        attempt pFloatArray |>> mapObj;
        attempt pBoolArray |>> mapObj;
        attempt pOffsetDateTimeArray |>> mapObj;
        attempt pLocalDateTimeArray |>> mapObj;
        attempt pLocalDateArray |>> mapObj;
        attempt pLocalTimeArray |>> mapObj;
        attempt pNestedArray |>> mapObj
    ]
```

I don't have time to test this at the moment, but I believe this should work for you.